# How to dynamically adapt textview size in constraint layout to different screen sizes?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, responsive-design, android-constraintlayout

**Screenshots**

1)[Samsung J6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6JWy.jpg)

2) [Lenovo Vibe X3 6 inch screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rN4O.jpg)

Problem is how can i adjust the textview of lyrics to increase height when more screen is available as in J6 model and less height when screen space is less,?
Or is there any way to avoid that extra weird looking space below the play/pause control buttonsin J6 model ? when i increase the space between textview and the buttons , J6 becomes correct and in lenovo model buttons go out of the screen??

My XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="660dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="239dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/albumcover"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_surround_sound_24px" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_more_vert_24px" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Human Nature"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_width="402dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:progressTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:thumbTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_pause_24px" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_skip_next_24px" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_skip_previous_24px" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView7"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_shuffle_24px" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView6"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_repeat_24px" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="Housee De Racket"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="this space is for lyrics "
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="01:23"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="01:24"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Provide screenshot please.

Comment: @kfrajer i dont enough reputations to post screen shot so i have included a link to it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove that `LinearLayout`;
2. Make the `ConstraintLayout` height to `match_parent`;
3. You want those controll buttons to be right at the bottom, so set bottom constraint to bottom of a parent;
4. `ProgressBar` bottom to top of controll buttons;
5. Time textviews bottom to top of controll buttons;
6. Move like that up, so you will leave only song cover to fill remaining height

Answer (score 2):

Check this piece out about [Autosizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)

There are actually a lot of flexibility in determining how you want your text view to resize. One of the examples in the doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp" />
```